# Cambiar en SweetAlert2 la tipografía del texto, titulo o botón

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

¿Cómo puedo cambiar la tipografía por defecto de SweetAlert2?

```
swal({

    type:"warning",
    title: "¡Advertencia!",
    text: "¡Mira este texto con otra tipografía y color!",
    showConfirmButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"

    });
```

Comment: Editando el CSS apropiado, por ejemplo: `.swal2-popup { ... }`. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Supongo que habrás leido la documentación de [Sweet Alert para Clases Personalizadas](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#customClass). Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo desde **css** utilizando la declaración `!important` en alguno de los casos:

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: "¡Advertencia!",
    text: "¡Mira este texto con otra tipografía y color!",
    showConfirmButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
})
```

```css
.swal2-title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px !important;
  color: green !important;
}

.swal2-html-container{
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: blue !important;
}

.swal2-confirm {
  background-color: orange !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```